# SQL Server database project gives warning 'Unresolved reference to object sp_executesql'

Tags: database-project

SQL Server database project gives warning 'Unresolved reference to object sp_executesql' when using sp_executesql inside a stored procedure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Expand references under your database and add reference to system database 'master'

[image]

Comment: And if you're working in a team, make sure everyone is on the same edition of Visual Studio so the path to that master.dacpac file is consistent.  (i.e., no mixing "community" with "pro" with "enterprise")  For some reason, MS placed those dacpacs inside that edition-specific path instead of a generic one. :/